# Creating a map with type interface to accept arbitrary data types via URL params

Tags: go

I want to convert URL parameters from a string, to the correct data type and store it in a map. I believe the type should be []interface, to store a list of multiple data types.

I am creating a key-value store, but at the moment, it only stores strings. I have read up on GOB to convert the data into bytes, but don't understand it.

I have tried type assertion, however, I don't believe in my case this will work as the data is coming from the URL which by default is already a string. How do I detect whether the entry is a string, int, boolean etc?

Map:

```
var data map[string][]string
```

handleFunc in the main func which calls the handleCreate func

```
r.HandleFunc("/insert/{key}/{value}", handleCreate).Methods("POST")
```

handleFunc function

```
func handleCreate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
params := mux.Vars(r)

k := params["key"]
v := params["value"]

data[k] = append(data[k], v)
fmt.Fprintf(w, "KEY: %v: VALUE: %v was inserted into the key-value store successfully", k, v)
}
```

A link to the full code:

https://github.com/RipRoss/TrainingProjects/blob/master/main.go

The expected result is to store the value given in the URL as what it is intended for. For example /dog/Zeus would store Zeus as a string with key 'dog' and /cash/1000 would store 1000 as type int with key 'cash'

Comment: Hey that URL no longer working, you still got the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried type assertion, however, I don't believe in my case this will work as the data is coming from the URL which by default is already a string. How do I detect whether the entry is a string, int, boolean etc?

In general it's not a very good idea to make things overly dynamic (makes reasoning about things more complicated than it needs to be). Better to define a struct and then read values into it.

That said, if we stick to the wording of your question, there are things you can do:

For example, create a generic type that can store multiple versions of a value, along with a flag to indicate whether it correctly parsed into that type:

```
type GenericValue struct {
    String string

    Integer int
    IntegerOK bool

    Float float64
    FloatOK bool

    Boolean bool
    BooleanOK bool
}

func ParseGenericValue(v string) GenericValue {
    var result GenericValue
    var err error
    result.String = v
    result.Integer, err = strconv.Atoi(v)
    result.IntegerOK = err == nil
    result.Float, err = strconv.ParseFloat(v, 64)
    result.FloatOK = err == nil
    result.Boolean, err = strconv.ParseBool(v)
    result.BooleanOK = err == nil
    return result
}
```

All this does is use the [strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/) package to try to parse the input string as an integer/float/boolean and if the parse is successful it makrs the corresponding `OK` field. For example, if `IntegerOK` is true then this indicates that parsing this string into an integer was successful.

The `GenericValue` struct still holds the original input string, so you can use it to check if this value is an integer and do something with it, or check if it's a string and do something else

```
var v = ParseGenericValue("2")

if v.IntegerOK {
    // do something with v.Integer
} else {
    // maybe just handle v.String in a different way
}
```

Comment: Hm, this looks like something that could work. Do you have time to give me more of an explanation as to what the ParseGenericValue func is doing?

Comment: sure, added some explanation

Comment: Sorry you updated. I'm getting undefined errors for IntegerOK, BooleanOK etc. Do i need to set those to type bool?

Comment: it's a struct. I missed the keyword.

Comment: Yeah, I made them type boolean and all is working. You sir, are a legend

Answer (score 0):

Check out this package which converts the URL params to struct with expected fields.This is useful, ofcourse when you know the expected data types.

https://github.com/gorilla/schema

e.g

```
type ServiceInput struct {
  Latitude                 float64  `schema:"latitude,required"` //add validations too
  Longitude                 float64  `schema:"longitude"`
}
```

...

```
r := new(ServiceInput)
urlParams := request.URL.Query() //request is http.Request

decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
if err := decoder.Decode(r, urlParams); err != nil {
    return nil, lib.ErrBadRequest{Err: err}
}
```

Now assuming request as GET /foo/bar?latitude=1.2&longitude=3.4, it will accordingly set the struct fields.

If you don't have any clue about field's type, then you have to try parsing to different type and check.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what the datatype they enter will be, unless i had them confirm which data type... such as '/dog/Zeus/string'... Do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: APIs are like contracts. I believe it would be better to define the url fields and their types in advance so as to avoid wonders tomorrow. For example if say ID param is string today and you have a DB column of type string modelled on it and tomorrow if somebody changes it to int since there is no contract, then your app would start crashing when comparing it to string DB field.

Comment: Okay, so a struct with a value for each type would be a viable option? Then when the URL is entered... /key/value/datatype... it would check the datatype entered and amend to the struct accordingly?

Comment: the following line gets the url params as a map:

    `request.URL.Query()`

and then schema's decoder object's struct method would try to decode to expected struct and err if there is any mismatch of type.